# In Go, is there a valid reason to turn GO111MODULE off?

Tags: go

I just started working through an online scientific-programming class that uses the Go language, which I have been eager to learn for a while.  The instructor strongly recommends setting `GO111MODULE=off` (i.e. disabling Go modules).  He doesn't really explain why, and, as this is an archived course (it was developed a few years ago), the instructor cannot easily be reached for questioning.

Can anyone think of a valid reason to disable such a powerful and useful feature?  Is there some drawback to modules in Go that I am unaware of?

Comment: No, not really. If and only if you have to work with code that predates modules and doesn't work with modules you _can_ switch back to the legacy old mode. As this course is old it might have made sense then.

Comment: [1/2] What Volker said. Basically, the idea is as follows: long time ago Go did not have the concept of "modules" (as sets of packages + tooling for managing versions of these sets and their dependencies), and had plain packages with no built-in support for versioning. In Go 1.11, support for modules was added as an experimental feature, in 1.13 Go would automatically switch into module-aware mode when it were to detect a module, and since 1.16 Go defaults to always work with modules. You swill can explicitly switch Go into legacy mode via `GO111MODULE=off` ("111" stands for v1.11, FWIW)…

Comment: [2/2] …but the only reason to do that is that you really have to work with a very old code using a contemporary Go version (current is 1.21, plus two versions back are still supported). You can look at that code from the course: if it does not contain a file named `go.mod` anywhere, it's pretty much a piece of legacy code and then the suggestion should be followed. Just be sure to _not_ have this directive active when you're working on a reasonably up-to-date code, or code of your own. Note that [the official intro docs](https://go.dev/doc/) suppose module-aware mode.

Comment: Well, [3/2] ;-) If you will need to work in legacy mode, take a look [there](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable), [there](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-GOPATH_and_Modules) and [there](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Legacy_GOPATH_go_get) (that's the same document), and [this archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20210112123438/https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html) of "How to write Go code".